# How do I connect my Rails app to MongoLab? "failed with error 13: "not authorized for query on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

This is my first time trying to deploy a Rails app using MongoDB and I'm having difficulty trying to connect it to my remote MongoDB database. I've spent the past two days researching and trying to fix it to no avail.

When I try to query anything, I get this error message:

```
Moped::Errors::QueryFailure: The operation: #<Moped::Protocol::Query
  @length=94
  @request_id=4
  @response_to=0
  @op_code=2004
  @flags=[]
  @full_collection_name="heroku_app36774115.apps"
  @skip=0
  @limit=-1
  @selector={"$query"=>{}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}}
  @fields=nil>
failed with error 13: "not authorized for query on heroku_app36774115.apps"
```

This is my mongoid.yml config for the production database:

```
production:
  sessions:
    default:
      hosts:
        - ds041831.mongolab.com:41831
      database: heroku_app36774115
      username: ENV['MONGOLAB_USERNAME']
      password: ENV['MONGOLAB_PASSWORD']
```

It seems like I can connect to the database from the shell (again, I'm new to MongoDB) when I run this code:

```
mongo ds041831.mongolab.com:41831/heroku_app36774115 -u <username> -p <password>
```

The current user configuration is:

```
{
    "_id": "heroku_app36774115.<username>",
    "user": "<username>",
    "db": "heroku_app36774115",
    "credentials": {
        "MONGODB-CR": "xxxx"
    },
    "roles": [
        {
            "role": "dbOwner",
            "db": "heroku_app36774115"
        }
    ]
}
```

Update: It was something stupid. I didn't realize I needed <% %> inside the ENV variable in my YML config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create a user with admin role

```
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "siteUserAdmin",
    pwd: "password",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "YOUR_DB_NAME_HERE" } ]
  }
)
```

then set username and password

```
production:
  sessions:
    default:
      hosts:
        - ds041831.mongolab.com:41831
      database: heroku_app36774115
      username: ENV['siteUserAdmin'] 
      password: ENV['password']
```

Comment: Hi Radulescu. I tried to create an admin, but I get this error: Error: couldn't add user: not authorized on admin to execute command { createUser: "siteUserAdmin", pwd: "xxx", roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "heroku_app36774115" } ], digestPassword: false, writeConcern: { w: "majority", wtimeout: 30000.0 } } at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1004

Answer (score 0):

1.Add a userAdminAnyDatabase to the admin db

```
$ mongo admin
> db.addUser({ user: "myadmin", pwd: "1234", roles: ["userAdminAnyDatabase"] })
```

2.Turn on authentication

```
auth = true
setParameter = enableLocalhostAuthBypass=0
```

3.connect using the new myadmin user to any database you want and add further users:

```
$ mongo another -u myadmin -p 1234
> db.addUser({ user: "user", pwd: "1234", roles: ["readWrite"] })
```